# Does the Akame Ga Kill! manga continue where the anime leaves off?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

The anime has ended at episode 24, "Akame ga Kill!".

Does the manga continue the story beyond the anime's conclusion?

Comment: Spoiler alert for the anime: 
short answer, no. the manga is very different from the anime. For example, Tatsumi and Mine are still alive. There are obviously similarities between the manga and anime but they follow different paths.